# Riemann Zeta Function?

Tags: gamma-function, riemann-zeta

> The Riemann Zeta Function has, for $Re(z)>1$, the following integral
>
> $\zeta(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\int_0^\infty dt\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t-1}$
>
> where $\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty dt t^{z-1}e^{-t}$ is the Euler Gamma Function.
>
> Show that for $Re(z)>0$ the Riemann Zeta Function can be expressed as
>
> $\zeta(z)=\frac{1}{(1-2^{1-z})\Gamma(z)}\int_0^\infty dt\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t+1}$

I'm totally lost here. I don't know how I can derive that alternate expression for the Zeta Function just from $Re(z)>0$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at how the first integral representation is derived. Think about how $(1 - 2^{1-z})\zeta(z)$ looks in comparison to $\zeta(z)$ (for $\operatorname{Re} z > 1$).

Comment: for $t > 0$ : $\frac{1}{e^t-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nt}, \frac{1}{e^t+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} e^{-nt}$ and for $n > 0$ : $\int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-nt}dt = \int_0^\infty (\frac{x}n)^{z-1} e^{-x}\frac{dx}{n} = n^{-z} \Gamma(z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that, for $t>0$,
$$
\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t+1}=\frac2{2^{z-1}}\frac{(2t)^{z-1}}{e^{2t}-1}-\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t-1}
$$ then one may integrate and use the above integral representation of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: this works only for $Re(z) > 1$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, one usually does it in two steps.

Comment: Not really 
$\Gamma(s)\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (-1)^{n+1}n^{-s} = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{1-(-1)^Ne^{-Nx}}{1+e^{-x}} dx$ and obviously for $Re(s) > 0$ , $\lim_{N \to \infty}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{e^{-Nx}}{1+e^{-x}} dx=0$

Comment: What you wrote is just another way... The hint above leads to $\zeta(z)=\frac{1}{(1-2^{1-z})\Gamma(z)}\int_0^\infty dt\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t+1}$ for $\Re z>1$ then easily extended to $\Re z>0$.

Comment: I have no problem with this proof, but I don't think analytic continuation is an obvious concept for the OP, so this should be an important part of your answer

Comment: Ok, if that is the case, he will freely pick up an appropriate answer.

Comment: The point is you wrote above "not really" when I said the hint were leading to a two steps proof, as if there was only one proof for those classic results...

Answer (score 0):

Noting that
$$
\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t+1}+\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t-1}=\frac{2 e^t t^{z-1}}{e^{2 t}-1},
$$
then
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t+1} d t+\int \frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t-1} d t=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2 e^t t^{z-1}}{e^{2 t}-1} d t
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2 e^t t^{z-1}}{e^{2 t}-1} d t
= & 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t} t^{z-1}}{1-e^{-2 t}} d z \\
= & 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} t^{z-1} e^{-(2 n+1) t} d t \\
=&2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(z)}{(2 n+1)^z} \\
=&2 \Gamma(z)\left[\zeta(z)-\frac{1}{z^z} \zeta(z)\right] \\
 =&\left(2-\frac{1}{2^{z-1}}\right) \Gamma(z) \zeta(z)
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t+1} d t & =\left(2-\frac{1}{2^z}\right) \Gamma(z) \zeta(z)-\Gamma(z) \zeta(z )\\
& =\left(1-\frac{1}{2^z}\right) \Gamma(z) \zeta(z)
\end{aligned}
$$